# How can I add a word to a list without it being separated by a comma when printing out the list?

Tags: python, list, insert

I am trying to add certain words to a list of only numbers.

```
french_toast_recipe = [1, 1, 1/2, 1/4, 4] #this is the beggining list
new_recipe = [] # this is the new recipie
user_servings = int(input("How many servings would you like?"))
divide_recipe = 4 / user_servings
new_recipe = []
for i in french_toast_recipe:
    new_recipe.append((i/divide_recipe))
new_recipe.insert(1, "egg(s)") # this is where I want to insert the word egg in the new list
 
print(new_recipe)
```

However, when I print it out it prints like this

```
[1.5, egg(s)]
```

However, I want it to print out like this

```
[1.5 egg(s), ]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can make `1.5` a string the `str()` and the add ` egg(s)` to the string.

Comment: Ideally the pairs of things would be tuples, e.g. `[(1.5, "egg(s)"), ...]` and then you could iterate it easily printing however you want, e.g. `for qty, item in recipe: print('%s %s' % (qty, item))`. If they're all individual entries as in your example then you have to iterate a little differently, e.g. `for i in range(len(new_recipe) / 2): print('%s %s' % (new_recipe[i * 2], new_recipe[i * 2 + 1]))`.